# C# reflection base class trouble

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I want to get value of field of base class, in child class, by name of field:

```
class A
{
    protected static double? x;
}

class B : A
{
     B()
       : base()
     {
         x = 13F;       
     }

    void test()
    {
         double? s = this.GetType().
           GetField("x", BindingFlags.NonPublic  | BindingFlags.Static).GetValue(null) as double?;
    }
}
```

why i have TargetException, when i call test() method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double? s = GetType()
            .GetField("x", BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
            .GetValue(null) as double?;
```

From [`System.Reflection.BindingFlags`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx):

> FlattenHierarchy: Specifies that
>   public and protected static members up
>   the hierarchy should be returned.
>   Private static members in inherited
>   classes are not returned. Static
>   members include fields, methods,
>   events, and properties. Nested types
>   are not returned.

I assume this is just a toy example to test reflecting static members in base types? Otherwise, it appears a little strange to use reflection in this context: `protected` members are visible to subclasses. You could just do:

```
double? s = x;
```

Comment: no, i have 20 variables, in base class, and i want to loop them, with some restriction on their names

Answer (score 1):

Add `BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy`:

```
       GetField("x", BindingFlags.NonPublic  | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy).GetValue(null) as double?;
```